# Disable all keys except enter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function so that when a textarea is filled with 80 characters the keyboard is disabled until the user presses enter to start a new line and then they can type again.

```
var len = 0;

$('#texttype').on("keypress", function() {
    len++;
});

$('#texttype').keyup(function(event) {
    var max = 80;

    if (len >= max) {
        $('#charNum').text('You have reached the limit.');
        $("#texttype").keydown(function(event) {
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

This code above works fine to disable the keyboard when the limit is reached but I cannot re-enable access for the life of me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you've tried to reset your counter on [enter].

Comment: All the methods I tried just broke the whole thing so I gave the code that worked so far, is that not right? I'm pretty new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var len = 0;
var max = 80;
$('#texttype').on("keypress", function (event) {
    len++;
    if (len >= max) {
        $('#charNum').text('You have reached the limit.');
        if (event.keyCode != 13){ return false;}
        else{ len = 0;}
    });
});
```

Comment: Work's perfectly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = 0;
var max = 80;

$('#texttype').on("keypress",function(){

     len++;
});


$('#texttype').keyup(function (event) {

   if (len >= max) {

    $('#charNum').text('You have reached the limit.');

   $("#texttype").keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {

            len = 0;
        }
        else {

            event.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```